# Extra space under bottom positioned TextBlock (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a problem with positioning the TextBlock element on the bottom of the newsfeed rectangle.
I attached the image of the problem (red arrow is pointing at it). There is too much extra space at the bottom of the "timeago" TextBlock.

You can see that the problem only occurs when the movie title is short enough to fit into first line.
I would guess that this makes the StackPanel to shrink and therefore move the TextBlock with time elapsed a bit higher.

I tried changing the MinHeight of parent StackPanel to lower values or even removing the property, but it doesn't seem to work.
I am guessing that the problem is with the "inner" StackPanel containing the *content*, *stars (not visible)* and "*timeago*"

[image: problem with extra space under TextBlock (red arrow is pointing at it) Tv Time Windows Phone]

This is the DataTemplate of my LongListSelector

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="12,2,5,4" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                           Opacity="0.75"
                           Margin="0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        Height="auto"
                        MinHeight="99"
                        Width="auto">

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          Background="#FFFFC700" 
                          Height="auto" 
                          Width="99">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                       Height="auto" 
                       Width="auto" 
                       Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                       Margin="0" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </Image>
            </Grid>


            <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,15,15,0" Text="{Binding Content}" Style="{StaticResource NewsFeedHighlitedContent}" FontSize="24" />

                <Grid Margin="10,5,0,15" Visibility="{Binding StarsVisibility}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{Binding StarOne}" Height="30" Margin="0,0" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding StarTwo}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding StarThree}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding StarFour}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding StarFive}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />

                </Grid>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="8,14,25,7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource NewsTimeAgoStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the style for "NewsTimeAgoStyle"

```
<Style x:Key="NewsTimeAgoStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP Light" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,14,20,0" />
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

Does anybody have any clue on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there extra spaces or blank string in the datasource for that binding?

Comment: Nope, there is no extra space or blank string in the datasource for this binding (I just checked it).
Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You could create the entire chunk out of a single grid.  Your issue is due to the expected behavior of the stack panel.  Don't use it.  Move the title into the grid, and set it's RowHeight  to `*`

Comment: Hey, Will thank you for your suggestion. I used the code that @NullPointer modified for me and it worked great ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but the problem might be because you are using `StackPanel` to display title and time ago text. I have changed your `DataTemplate` little bit to use `Grid` Panel. Try this and see this make any difference

```
<DataTemplate>
<Grid Margin="12,2,5,4" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                       Opacity="0.75"
                       Margin="0,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0" 
            Background="Transparent" 
            Height="auto"
            MinHeight="99">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="99"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      Background="#FFFFC700">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                   Height="auto" 
                   Width="auto" 
                   Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                   Margin="0" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            </Image>
        </Grid>


        <Grid Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,15,15,0" Text="{Binding Content}" Style="{StaticResource NewsFeedHighlitedContent}" FontSize="24" />

            <Grid Margin="10,5,0,15" Visibility="{Binding StarsVisibility}" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding StarOne}" Height="30" Margin="0,0" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Image Source="{Binding StarTwo}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image Source="{Binding StarThree}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                <Image Source="{Binding StarFour}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
                <Image Source="{Binding StarFive}" Height="30" Width="30" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />

            </Grid>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="8,14,25,7" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource NewsTimeAgoStyle}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Dear **Null Pointer**, I am impressed. Thank you for your help. This code works great, the problem was solved immediately!
Thank you!